# Ajax jquery popup data binding passing issue! MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

View page has a web grid and each grid row having more details has its row bonded with the primary key of the grid row. I have a buttons at top of this view, which help me perform some actions. Now on one of these actions I display a popup with 3 buttons, popup is rendered by calling ajax and a partial view with 3 buttons. user clicks and proper controller is called but i am not to pass the primary key to pop up and hence to controller.

Now on grid row select I bind the primary key to the 3 buttons value. But after popup open's I am unable to retrieve this value! Could you please guide as to the correct approach to go about further to pass value to the popup and send back again on click to controllers(which I believe through ajax will work).

I want to access value of primary key of selected row on popup page? Thank you for reading.

Any help or heads up would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the code / logic / algorithm what you have implemented so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the primary key of your row to the **"Value"** of your 3 buttons and you want to get back this "Value" on whatever action, you should use the general attribute .Val().

**There's an example :**

```
<script>
   $("button").click(function () {
     var text = $(this).text(); //this is where the primary key is getting back.
     $("input").val(text);
   });
</script>
```

More information about .val() attribute [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/).